# Youtube API - PHP - How to modify the start time of an existing broadcast?

Tags: php, youtube-api

I can already create broadcast events in YouTube Live, now I'm trying to modify existing ones with the update API.

The problem is the VideoSnippet library doesn't allow this, it must be done in another way.

(This PHP function is to be called by the frontend with an ajax request)

```
function updateBroadcast(){
    if(!isset($client)){
        $client = getClient();
    }
    $streamData = $_POST['streamData'];

    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['google_access_token']);
    $service =  new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

        try {
            $videoId = $streamData['id'];

            // Call the API's videos.list method to retrieve the video resource.
            $listResponse = $service->videos->listVideos("snippet",
                array('id' => $videoId));

            if (empty($listResponse)) {
                return  json_encode(sprintf('Can\'t find a video with video id: %s', $videoId));
            } else {
                // Since the request specified a video ID, the response only
                // contains one video resource.
                $video = $listResponse[0];
                $videoSnippet = $video['snippet'];

                $videoSnippet->setTitle($streamData['eventName']);
                $videoSnippet->setDescription($streamData['eventCategory']);
                $videoSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($streamData['eventDateTime'])
            }

        } catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
            echo sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
                htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
            echo sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
                htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
        }
        return json_encode("Video Updated");
    }
}
```

It throws this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet::setScheduledStartTime() in /var/www/html/production/app/empowerir/php/videoStreaming/functions.php on line 242

Line 242 is:

```
$videoSnippet->setScheduledStartTime($streamData['eventDateTime'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error, it should already tell you what the problem is:

> Call to undefined method
>   Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet::setScheduledStartTime()

Looking at [LiveBroadcasts.update](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update), there is no such method `setScheduledStartTime` (looks like you invented it on the fly). If you want to update `snippet.scheduledStartTime` property, you'd have to set that in the request body of your `LiveBroadcasts.update` request.

Comment: The question is: "how to update a live broadcast using YouTube's PHP library?". How do I call the update method? How do I pass the parameters?

Comment: i cant write code for you mate cause I dont work on PHP. I expect you to know how to use your tools instead of inventing methods on the fly xD